# Css background text color space

Tags: css, text, background

I want to put background color on my text in my div but I want a background color only on text not on spaces... how I can do that. Is there some trick?

```
<div class="for">Maintenance Reliability Comfor</div>

display: inline-block;
padding: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
background-color: rgb(98, 206, 38);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PfLkD/

Comment: Could you use this. Rather forcing things...but http://jsfiddle.net/Fico/Hs8KA/

Comment: yes I know for span but its not a soltion... thanks a lot

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/c7fBp/ :)

Comment: @OneTrickPony, Yeap!  I buy that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with jQuery:

```
$('div').each(function() {

    var words = $(this).text().split(' ');

    $(this).empty().html(function() {

        for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                $(this).append('<span>' + words[i] + '</span>');
            } else {
                $(this).append(' <span>' + words[i] + '</span>');
            }
        }

    });

});
```

This code put `<span>`tags around each word, so you don't need to wrote one by one.

And then...: `.for span {background:red;}`

A [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/stmhj/1/).

Answer (score 0):

There is two way to accomplish that, using `span` like @Fico told you (http://jsfiddle.net/Fico/Hs8KA) or using `text-shadow` like @OneTrickPony (http://jsfiddle.net/c7fBp/)

Keep in mind browser support some version of IE doesn't handle well the text-shadow effect.